# Getting specfic values related to result after using pythonwekawrapper3

Tags: python-3.x, weka

I am using Pythonwekawrapper3 for attribute selection so i can remove the remaining attributes and use selected ones in python code to make an ensemble learner on it. But i am facing a problem in getting "Selected attributes:" part only from results the weka wrapper gives. What i want is a variable with all the selected attributes in it but I don't know how.

I have searched all over web for it but unable to find a way to get on selected attributes only from result_string.

```
search = ASSearch(classname="weka.attributeSelection.GeneticSearch", options=["-Z", "50", "-G", "100", "-C", "0.9","-M", "0.1"])
evaluator = ASEvaluation(classname="weka.attributeSelection.CfsSubsetEval", options=["-P", "1", "-E", "1"])
attsel = AttributeSelection()
attsel.search(search)
attsel.evaluator(evaluator)
attsel.select_attributes(data)

print("# attributes: " + str(attsel.number_attributes_selected))
print("attributes: " + str(attsel.selected_attributes))
print("result string:\n" + attsel.results_string)
```

|Selected attributes: 2,3,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 #

variable=[2,3,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AttributeSelection.selected_attributes` returns a numpy array with the 0-based indices of the selected attributes ([documentation](http://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.html#weka.attribute_selection.AttributeSelection.selected_attributes)).

If you want to have a list instead, simply use `list(...)`, e.g.:

```py
list_of_sel_atts = list(attsel.selected_attributes))
print(list_of_sel_atts)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just new to python so missed it.